42 Character Long Domain Name, Exception?
Without getting too specific, I am a photographer trying to improve my SEO. The other day, I noticed that when I typed my website name into Google, my website doesn’t appear as a search result. I am also not ranking at all for my photography services in my local area.
My company name is basically my state and the two specific photography services that I specialize in and then the word photography. In total, my company name is about 42 characters long.
I saw that my full company name is available as a domain name and was thinking about snatching it up to possibly improve my local ranking. My question is, would a 42 character long domain name be too long even though it matched my company name, exactly? My current domain name is basically the letters or abbreviation of my companies name; basically, nonsensical letters. I was thinking of using the shorter domain for marketing purposes like email and business cards, but the longer one for my actual web presence.
What do you guys think?
THANKS!!

Domain names have very little impact on SEO nowadays, aside from ccTLDs. See these related posts: Domain name benefit in SEO and Will having multiple domains improve my seo? and What are the best ways to improve a site's position in Google?.
